# How to migrate from Teensey LC to Final PCB?

Tags: pcb

Im an new to Teensey LC. So the following question is a beginners question on Teensey LC.
How do I migrate from a Teensey LC to a final PCB?
Is it similar to migrating an Ardunio to a bread board -where DIP ATMEGA is used , with crystal, and capacitors and so on?-if not similar whats the procedure?
If so where do I get DIP version of CPU in Teensey LC?

Comment: Different versions of Teensy use differnet microcontrollers. However I think the designs are open-source, so you could just copy the Teensy board design on your own PCb layout. If you're prototyping on a solderless breadboard, the whole Teensy board itself plugs in as if it was a big IC. I don't think you will find DIP versions ARM microcontrollers, the pin count is too many, and nobody uses DIP in volume anymore. All the new stuff is SMT not DIP.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply duplicate the parts of the circuit you are using (including the crystal). The schematic diagram is published here:
https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/schematic_lc.gif

However the microcontroller chip (Kinetis KL26 Sub-Family) is NOT available in a DIP package as DIP is a dying technology and the chip has too many pins for DIP.

Comment: It doesnt seem like you can do that by hand-solder the SMD Kinetis CPU on final pcb- as you can do with arduino to final pcb